# Suggestions for building Localisation algorithm for 5 classes

Tags: keras, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

I'm currently working on a project for *object detection* using a very light CNN model , but till now I was able to classify all 5 classes with ~94% accuracy with 5 layered CNN using Keras and now I'm using sliding window algorithm to localise the 5 class objects ,but the accuracy of this algorithm is very poor i.e ~40 % and few bounding boxes are at random , before this I tried YOLO v3 tiny model and tensorflow model as well , but I need to reduce the time taken to predict each frame. can anyone suggest any approaches to attempt this problem